# Ubuntu freezes upon installation Lenovo ThinkPad W541

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 on my Lenovo ThinkPad W541 but the installation freezes shortly after it begins.

It gets stuck  on frame buffer device.

The laptop is currently running on Windows 10, but I want to switch to Linux.

I've tried changing the Bios from Legacy To UEFI, but it has still the same problem. The installation freezes when it reaches frame buffer device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same problem on my Lenovo W541.

I followed the below steps and it worked for me.

1. Select "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)" option, instead of "Try or Install Ubuntu"
2. Select "Install 3rd party software for graphics..."

Hope this helps.